# Discrete time queue markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

Consider  a  queue  at  a  counter,  in  which $X_n$ denotes the number of customers who are either waiting or being served at time $n$.Suppose $Y_{n+1}$ new customers join the queue between $n$ and $n+1$, and whenever $X_n > 0$, $Z_{n+1}$ customers are processed and leave the queue.

(a) Suppose we assume that $X_0,Y_1, Z_1, Y_2, Z_2,...$, are all mutually independent.  Assume in addition that ${Y_i}$ are independent and identically distributed Bernoulli $(p)$ random variables for some $p∈(0,1)$, and suppose that ${Z_i}$ are independent  and  identically  distributed  Bernoulli  $(q)$ random  variables for some $q∈(0,1)$, with $p <1$.  Find the stationary distribution $π$ for the Markov chain ${X_n}$.  Is it unique?

(b)Compute $E_π[X_n]$, where $E_π$ denotes the expectation of $X_n$ given that the initial distribution of the chain $X_0$ is given by the stationary distribution $π$ computed in (a).

What I have so far is that $X_{n+1} = X_n + Y_{n+1} - l_{X_n>0}Z_{n+1}$, where l is the indicator function. In a stationary distribution $π$ for Markov Chain $X_n$, $π = π*P$. I am given that $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are Bernoulli random variables, but I am unsure how to put together this information to create the transition probability matrix $P$ and then find the matrix $π$ made invariant by $P$.

For part b, I am not too sure how to find $E_π[X_n]$. I was thinking that because it is invariant, I could turn $X_{n+1} = X_n + Y_{n+1} - l_{X_n>0}Z_{n+1}$ into $X_{n} = X_{n-1} + Y_{n} - l_{X_{n-1}>0}Z_{n}$ and then find $E[X_{n} = X_{n-1} + Y_{n} - l_{X_{n-1}>0}Z_{n}]$.Because I know that $Y$ and $Z$ are mutually independent, We can do: $E[X_{n}] = E[X_{n-1}] + E[Y_{n}] - El_{X_{n-1}>0}Z_{n}]$. So, $E[X_{n}] = E[X_{n-1}] + p - El_{X_{n-1}>0}Z_{n}]$. I know that the $E[Z_n] = q$, but I don't know how to simplify from what I currently have or what $E[X_{n-1}]$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very first goal should be to turn this description into a Markov chain. You know the states of the Markov chain: at any time, there can be $0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$ customers in the line. So it remains to figure out the transition probabilities.

Suppose that at step $n$ there are $X_n=k$ customers in the line. Then at step $n+1$, three things can happen:

- With probability $p(1-q)$, $Y_{n+1} = 1$ and $Z_{n+1}=0$: one customer joins the line and none leave. So at step $n+1$ there will be $X_{n+1} = k+1$ customers in the line.
- With probability $(1-p)q$, $Y_{n+1} = 0$ and $Z_{n+1}=1$: no new customers arrive, but one customer leaves. So at step $n+1$ there will be $X_{n+1} = k-1$ customers in the line.
- Otherwise, either nothing happens, or one customer arrives and another leaves; in either case, $X_{n+1} = k$.

Only if $X_n = 0$ do we do something else. In this case, we simply have a probability $p$ of having $X_{n+1} = 1$, and a probability $1-p$ of having $X_{n+1} = 0$.

Altogether, the Markov chain looks like:

[image: markov chain]

(I have left the loops unlabeled; at every state, there's some probability of staying in that state which can be inferred from the probability of leaving it.)

*Now* you can proceed with actually solving the problem. You could write down the transition probabilities in the variables $\pi_0, \pi_1, \pi_2, \dots$; there will be infinitely many equations, but almost all of them will be very similar.

An alternate approach is to use the time-reversibility equations. In these case, these say that the fraction of transitions going from state $k$ to $k+1$ (which is $\pi_k$ times the transition probability $P_{k,k+1}$) is equal to the fraction of transitions going from state $k+1$ to $k$ (which is $\pi_{k+1}$ times the transition probability $P_{k+1,k}$). Solving these is much more straightforward: you immediately get an expression for $\pi_1$ in terms of $\pi_0$, $\pi_2$ in terms of $\pi_1$, and so on.

Finally, once you've solved for the stationary distribution, you should have
$$
   \mathbb E_{\pi}[X_n] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \cdot \pi_k.
$$
This does not depend on $n$: if you start by sampling $X_0$ from the stationary distribution $\pi$, then $X_1, X_2, \dots$ should also all follow the stationary distribution.